# Add a list of frequent or registered Stack Exchange sites in the left menu for faster browsing

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been using Stack Exchange a lot recently, going from Stack Overflow to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), to Meta Stack Overflow, to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour), etc.

I felt like it was hard to switch from one to another. The fastest way I found was to click on a recent Inbox notification. It would help to have the Stack Exchange site I am registered to in a list in the left menu, so I could click and switch fast.

I found an "ish" related question on Meta Stack Exchange, but none seemed as clear as what I'm proposing/seeing as something simple that could help.  I've put my proposition in an image:

[image: Finally working]

Comment: I'm just a new guy, but I've been using the icon in the upper-right corner. It's to the right of the "?" icon. My communities are shown there.

Comment: Hum, interresting, i would still prefer to have it in the left menu but i dont feel like this is a general enough issue/preference.

Comment: I agree. It would be nice & faster.

Comment: The left navigation is all specific to the site you're currently on. Adding other sites to that area could cause confusion.

Comment: Some of us have the left side navigation disabled completely so it would not be helpful at all.

Comment: Then maybe left side is not the exact answer to the problem, but would there be a way to have it in first level display at least? But as expected, it seems like meta users dont have this issues and that meta discussions is not for these type or question (downvote), il just delete it and move on

Comment: @Dave Wait, there's a left side navigation?

Comment: Well I thought there was/used to be .... haven't seen anything in so long I may be mistaken now. Yep, it's the menu that you can drop down but turn off as sticky on the left side. In your profile under settings ... Hide left navigation.

Comment: Sorry, that was a joke. I hid it when it was first added it and don't think I've used it ever since.

Comment: Workarounds: 1) The web browser's bookmark feature 2) [Extended bookmarks page](http://www.pmortensen.eu/jump.html) (requires manual updating, though. But it works for non-Stack Exchange sites)

Comment: @PatatesPilées - so you basically saying: "when I asked you to vote on my proposal by adding 'feature-request' tag I *didn't ask to express disagreement*, not liking my proposal is nonwelcoming"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov (*deleting all of my 4th salty comment, deep breath*) yeah, well, i maybe did not fully understood how meta worked i wont bother y'all anymore

Answer (score 3):

You can use the upper-right menu for that.
Under **Your Communities** it normally lists the five sites where you have the highest reputation but you can edit the list and add any site you want including meta sites.

[image]

Comment: I cant add my image (*insert 20th try frustration*) but i was proposing to add it to the left menu (under Users maybe) so it's in first level not inside another menu.